# Wordpress database error - Error in SQL syntax - I can't identify any error?

Tags: database, mysql, wpdb

I am trying to write function that checks whether an email address is stored in my database or not. I've written the following PHP code::

```
function check_my_users( $email_address ) {
     global $wpdb;
     $my_table_name = $wpdb->prefix . 'my_users';

     $result = $wpdb->get_var( $wpdb->prepare( 'SELECT email FROM %s WHERE email = %s', $my_table_name, $email_address ) );

     if( $result !== NULL )
         return true;

     return false;
 }
```

The function always returns false. Additionally, the following query is printed after calling the function: `SELECT email FROM 'wp_my_users' WHERE email = 'mail@example.com'`.

Additionally, the following is written to the debug log:

```
WordPress database error You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''wp_my_users' WHERE email = 'mail@example.com'' at line 1 for query SELECT email FROM 'wp_my_users' WHERE email = 'mail@example.com' made by […]
```

(I added the elipsis)

What is wrong with my function, why do I get that error? To me, everything looks good.

Comment: This is a **SQL syntax** question, *not* a **WordPress** question.

Comment: While that is completely true, I wasn't able to know that before getting an answer. It also could have been that there are Wordpress functions that handle the task of my function, for example.

Comment: "**`You have an error in your SQL syntax`** seems rather explicit to me...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want the query to look like this:

```
SELECT email FROM wp_my_users WHERE email = 'mail@example.com'
```

instead of this:

```
SELECT email FROM 'wp_my_users' WHERE email = 'mail@example.com'
```

So try to construct your query with:

```
 $sql = "SELECT email FROM {$my_table_name} WHERE email = %s";
 $result = $wpdb->get_var( $wpdb->prepare( $sql, $email_address ) );
```

where you don't need to escape the table name, since it's constructed it in a safe way.

Comment: Ah that makes sense, of course I only need to prepare user input. Another thing I just noticed is the importance of double quotes. Thank you for your help!